# Node js how to read parameters from a get request

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, express, mongoose

i'm trying to write a get request with node js the classic get request send all data base as `res.json` and as you see in the data base code `imei.name` take a value every time and i want to write a get methode to have only a  special `imei.name` get methode in a res.json

```
router.get('/gettdata', (req, res, next) => {
    Post.find()
        .then((posts) => {
            res.json(posts);
            console.log(posts);
            console.log("ok" + JSON.stringify(req.body) + req.body.imei);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
});
```

that's my get methode i want to change it and as you see there is the data base

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eb7f90fb88d8d4d94184333"),
        "imei" : {
                "name" : "bokhhjbr",
                "modele" : "5486"
        },
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eb7fb9cb88d8d4d94184334"),
        "imei" : {
                "name" : "865566048694354",
                "modele" : "CPH1803"
        },
        "__v" : 0
}
```

for more information you can add some comments i need any help and thank you

Comment: what is the exact error which you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the required `imei name` as parameter and then, the query can be modified as `{ 'imei.name': req.params.imei }`.

In that case you do not need to console the imei value in request body.

You can update the route method as follows

```
router.get('/gettdata/:imei', (req, res, next) => {
  Post.find({ 'imei.name': req.params.imei })
    .then((posts) => {
      res.json(posts);
      console.log(posts);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
});
```